# Issue on sum table total sql codeigniter

Tags: sql, codeigniter

I have a little problem when I want to make the total sum of the column by id.

Table products

```
id   code    name        price  quantity
522  123     Product 1     12      4
```

Table purchase_items

```
id  product_id  quantity
1      522            5
2      522            1
```

Table sale_items

```
id  product_id  quantity
1      522            1
2      522            1
```

function codeigniter:

```
$products = $this->alerts->select('products.id as productid, products.code as code, products.name, products.price, sum(sale_items.quantity)')
      ->from('products');
      $this->alerts->join('sale_items', 'products.id = sale_items.product_id');           
      $this->alerts->group_by("products.id");

      $products = $this->alerts->select('products.id as productid, products.code as code, products.name, products.price, sum(purchase_items.quantity)')
      ->from('products');
      $this->alerts->join('purchase_items', 'products.id = purchase_items.product_id');           
      $this->alerts->group_by("products.id");


        $this->alerts->unset_column('productid');

        foreach ($this->result_array() as $product)
        {
            $products[] = $product['record'];
        }

        return $products;
    }
```

The issue is that the result for

```
purchase_items the result is 12
sale_items      the result is 4
```

Why is taking the result x 2 ?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think [my answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13651446/multiple-left-joins-how-to/13652061#13652061) should tell you why...  It's because you're not thinking in combined sets, basically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are joining purchasing activity to sales activity via your item master (products table). As a result, the number of rows for purchasing that are included in the sum depend on how many rows in sales you have; and vice versa for sales.

You need to separate those queries either as separate SQL statements that you combine in the view, or you can use a SQL `UNION ALL` to combine two statements: one for purchases and one for sales.

Two statements:

```
$this->alerts
            ->select('products.id as productid, products.code as code, products.name, products.price, sum(purchase_items.quantity)')
            ->from('products');
            $this->alerts->join('purchase_items', 'products.id = purchase_items.product_id');
                $this->alerts->group_by("products.id");
            echo "Total Purchases";
            echo $this->alerts->generate();


 $this->alerts
            ->select('products.id as productid, products.code as code, products.name, products.price, sum(sale_items.quantity)')
            ->from('products');
            $this->alerts->join('sale_items', 'products.id = sale_items.product_id');           
                $this->alerts->group_by("products.id");
            echo "Total Sales";
            echo $this->alerts->generate();
```

Or, in SQL:

```
$results = $this->db->query('
    SELECT products.id as productid, products.code as code, products.name, products.price, ''Purchase'' as transaction, sum(purchase_items.quantity)
    FROM products
    JOIN purchase_items ON products.id = purchase_items.product_id
    GROUP BY products.id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT products.id as productid, products.code as code, products.name, products.price, ''Sale'' as transaction sum(sales_items.quantity)
    FROM products
    JOIN sales_items ON products.id = sales_items.product_id
    GROUP BY products.id')->result_array();

// Echo $results....
```

**Edit:**
I'm not entirely sure what you have in your `Alerts` model, but in your revised query you are assigning a SQL statement twice to the variable `$products` but not executing the statements?

Also make sure your Alerts model extends `CI_Model`.

In more standard Codeigniter syntax, I would do something like this:

```
    // In Controller, assuming the Alerts model is loaded, and using method chaining.

    // Get all sales. By the way, you normally have to group on all columns *not* being aggregated. You might
    // get unexpected results by grouping on price, unless the price never changes.
    $this->alerts->select('products.id as productid, products.code, products.name, products.price, sum(sale_items.quantity) as quantity')
          ->from('products')
          ->join('sale_items', 'products.id = sale_items.product_id')
          ->group_by('products.id, products.code, products.name, products.price');
    $sales = $this->alerts->get()->result_array();

    // Get all purchases
    $this->alerts->select('products.id as productid, products.code, products.name, products.price, sum(purchase_items.quantity) as quantity')
          ->from('products')
          ->join('purchase_items', 'products.id = purchase_items.product_id')
          ->group_by(products.id, products.code, products.name, products.price);
    $purchases = $this->alerts->get()->result_array();

    // Put it all together
    $products = array_merge($sales, $purchases);

    // And now do something with your combined results $products. Send to view, echo etc.
```

Comment: I understand, so, no way to get sum on codeigniter from 2 different tables. im using echo $this->alerts->generate(); for serverside datatables. don't know how to construct on this way.

Comment: You can get what you want by running two Active Record queries, and then combining the results in your view.

Comment: I have updated the question, the problem now is that i cannot get the final result, because im getting fatal error on Call to a member result_array()

Comment: @Dario See update with revised suggestion. By the way, normally you would need to `GROUP ON` all columns not being aggregated (summed), so I included those. But your price column will cause extra rows to appear if your price changes.