# Sum more than 1 table from SQL on codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

need a small help to figure out this situation.
I see that codeigniter is not supporting UNION and i want to figure out this method to get the  total sum for 2 tables, with same id of product.

The issue is that on sum 2 tables, the values are duplicating or multiplicative.

Link to [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/17b30/1)

Structure :

```
create table products
(id int, name varchar(9));
insert into products 
(id, name)
values
(1,'Product 1'),
(2,'Product 2'),
(3,'Product 3');


create table p_items
(puid int, prid int, quantity int);
insert into p_items
(puid, prid, quantity)
values
(11,1,100),
(11,2,100),
(11,2,100),
(14,2,100),
(14,3,100),
(15,3,100);

create table s_items
(puid int, prid int, quantity int);
insert into s_items
(puid, prid, quantity)
values
(11,1,1),
(11,2,1),
(11,2,1),
(13,2,1),
(15,3,1),
(13,3,1);
```

Execute in normal SQL:

```
select a.puid, b.name, a.prid, sum(a.quantity) as P_ITEMS, sum(c.quantity) as S_ITEMS
from p_items a
join products b
on b.id = a.prid
join s_items c
on c.prid = a.prid
group by a.prid;
```

Codeigniter Function:

```
$this->alerts
            ->select('products.id as productid, products.name, sumt(p_items.quantity), sum(s_items.quantity)', FALSE)
            ->from('products')
            ->join('p_items', 'products.id = p_items.prid', 'left')
            ->join('s_items', 'products.id = s_items.prid')
            ->group_by("products.id");
            echo $this->alerts->generate();
```

Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: You already asked this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14777949/issue-on-sum-table-total-sql-codeigniter)

Comment: Hello Wolf, yes but here im asking how to get the normal sql in codeigniter not using union and asking why the values are X. no offenses. you get me the best response. but still looking for a solution on this.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is your producing a cartesian product and thus getting your duplicated sums.  Look at Product ID 3 for example.  You're associating that with p_items prid = 3.  By itself, that would return you 200.  However, once you then join on s_items prid = 3, now for each row in s_items, it has to match with each row in p_items.  Meaning:

```
14 3 100 15 3 1
14 3 100 15 3 1
15 3 100 15 3 1
15 3 100 15 3 1
---------------
     400      4
```

Besides the product table, which table is your master table?  If you use p_items, you want get row 13 from s_items.  Likewise, if you use s_items, you won't get rows 14 from p_items.

You can accomplish this using a subquery:

```
select b.id, 
  b.name, 
  P_ITEMS, 
  S_ITEMS
from products b
  left join 
    (SELECT prid, SUM(quantity) as P_Items
     FROM p_items
     GROUP BY prid)
     a on b.id = a.prid
  left join 
    (SELECT prid, SUM(quantity) as S_Items
     FROM s_items
     GROUP BY prid)
     c on c.prid = a.prid
group by b.id, b.name
```

And the updated Fiddel: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/62b45/12

Good luck.

Comment: ThAnks Sr sgeddes. the main table is products. i made the sql with p_items. but normall need to be products because have unique id. and p_items and s_items have the quantity purchased and quantity sold.

Comment: Can be an option» having p_items.prid = products.id ? or where ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the best way to get the answer you want is with a union query, and codeigniter does not let you write one, don't use codeigniter to write your query.  Put it in a stored procedure and call the stored procedure with codeigniter.